# How to find references to a string constant in a disassembled program code?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I'm trying to disassemble a program using `ndisasm`. I've found out that it does not distinguish between constants, metadata, and program instructions. I.e.:

```
00020CA3  00426F            add [edx+0x6f],al
00020CA6  726C              jc 0xd14
00020CA8  61                db 0x61
00020CA9  6E                outsb
00020CAA  6420432B          and [fs:ebx+0x2b],al
00020CAE  2B                db 0x2b
00020CAF  202D20436F70      and [0x706f4320],ch
00020CB5  7972              jns 0xd29
00020CB7  69                db 0x69
00020CB8  67                a32
00020CB9  68                db 0x68
00020CBA  7420              jz 0xcdc
00020CBC  31                db 0x31
00020CBD  39                db 0x39
00020CBE  39                db 0x39
00020CBF  31                db 0x31
00020CC0  20426F            and [edx+0x6f],al
00020CC3  726C              jc 0xd31
00020CC5  61                db 0x61
00020CC6  6E                outsb
00020CC7  6420496E          and [fs:ecx+0x6e],cl
00020CCB  746C              jz 0xd39
00020CCD  2E00446976        add [cs:ecx+ebp*2+0x76],al
```

is actually a string constant:

```
00020CA4  Borland C++ - Copyright 1991 Borland Intl.\x00
```

Null-terminated strings are easy to find, I just converted hex codes back to ASCII.

So, my question is: how can I find references to those strings in the assembly code?

I made a dummy try to search by the start position of a string constant (i.e. 0x20CA4), but it didn't help.

Comment: Yes, `ndisasm` is a very primitive disassembler.  For reverse engineering you probably want a more sophisticated tool.  [radare2](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2) is one that's often recommended.

Comment: Well, In the code above You can see that printed instructions are random. They are not connected to create some logical structure and to generate sensible output. So this could mean that this is data area. Best solution is to find program which converts hex bytes to ascii. If ascii is random = code, if ascii is readable text = data. Also check what instructions say, if there is code like this for example `mov si,bx loadsb cmp al,0` this means `si` contains offset to what to print. Or every other function that prints text on the screen.

Answer (score -1):

You're probably better off opening the executable in a hex editor. Those almost always come with an ASCII display off to the side.

Comment: A hex editor doesn't necessarily include a disassembler. Use the right tools for the task at hand, some tasks are better dealt with with hex editors, others disassemblers.

Comment: Ok, I thought by "references to a string constant" meant the constant itself, rather than a pointer to it. I must not have read the question completely.